# Question about spinor inner products

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, spinors

Let a 2D spinor be given by
$$\chi_2(p)=\pmatrix{\xi^1\\\xi^2}+i\pmatrix{\xi^3\\\xi^4}$$
with the $\xi^i$'s being real for $i=\{1,2,3,4\}$.
Assume, now, that I want to represent this spinor by a real-valued 4D column, i.e. something of the form
$$\chi_4(p)=\pmatrix{\xi^1\\\xi^2\\\xi^3\\\xi^4}$$
Can this be done? If yes, how? If not, why?

**Some thoughts of mine:**

**First thought:** Since we are changing representation, we should also keep in mind that quantities that are given by spinor "inner" products, should remain invariant! So, in the 2D case if
$$\chi_2^{\dagger}(p)=\pmatrix{\xi^1&\xi^2}-i\pmatrix{\xi^3&\xi^4}$$
and therefore
$$\chi_2^{\dagger}(p)\chi_2(p)=(\xi^1)^2+(\xi^2)^2+(\xi^3)^2+(\xi^4)^2+
i[\xi^1\xi^3+\xi^2\xi^4-\xi^3\xi^1-\xi^4\xi^2]=
\sum_{i=1}^4(\xi^i)^2$$
It is easy to see that $\chi_4^{\dagger}(p)\chi_4(p)=\sum_{i=1}^4(\xi^i)^2$, so the inner product is invariant!

**First Question:** This is a property that should always be satisfied when we change representations regardless of the fact that we are going to a higher dimensional representation from a lower dimensional representation, correct?

**Second thought:** What about products of the form $\chi_2^{\dagger}(p)\sigma^a\chi_2(p), \ a=\{1,2,3\}$, where $\sigma^a$ is the $a-$th Pauli matrix?

**Second question:** Should they also be invariant? And if they should, should the fact that they need to be invariant, restrict the form of the 4x4 matrices, that are probably given in a form with blocks of $\sigma^a$?
For instance, if they should be invariant, then $\Sigma^a_{4\times4}$ in  $\chi_4^{\dagger}(p)\Sigma^a_{4\times4}\chi_4(p)$ should be somehow determined by requiring
$$\chi_2^{\dagger}(p)\sigma^a\chi_2(p)=
\pmatrix{\xi^1&\xi^2}\sigma^a\pmatrix{\xi^1\\\xi^2}+
\pmatrix{\xi^3&\xi^4}\sigma^a\pmatrix{\xi^3\\\xi^4}+i
\bigg[
\pmatrix{\xi^1&\xi^2}\sigma^a\pmatrix{\xi^3\\\xi^4}-
\pmatrix{\xi^3&\xi^4}\sigma^a\pmatrix{\xi^1\\\xi^2}
\bigg]$$
to be equal to $\chi_4^{\dagger}(p)\Sigma^a_{4\text{x}4}\chi_4(p)$. In this case,
$$\Sigma^a_{4\times4}=\pmatrix{\sigma^a&i\sigma^a\\-i\sigma^a &\sigma^a}$$
Is this line of reasoning correct?

**Bonus Question:** Is a similarity transformation taking us from the 2D rep to the 4D rep?